# HIghcharts Rendered Label - Padding not working for on the right side of label, rectangle created by getBBox() overlaps the text

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am creating labels in highcharts using render function. It gets displayed properly in the web page but when I export it to PDF file, the label outer boundary which I create using the getBBox method overlaps the text as shown in attached image. [screenshot of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUDUU.png)

Please find below the code I am using -

```
$('#chartContainer0')
        .highcharts(
                {
                    credits : false,
                    colors : highColors,
                    chart : {
                        type : 'bar',
                        height : 500,
                        events : {
                            load : function() {
                                var label = this.renderer
                                        .label(
                                                "* applicable after CN review<br/>"
                                                        + "** applicable after baseline results are available <br/>"
                                                        + "*** applicable after final results are available")
                                        .css({
                                            color : '#222',
                                            fontSize : '10px'
                                        }).attr({
                                            'stroke' : 'silver',
                                            'stroke-width' : 1,
                                            'r' : 5,
                                            'padding' : 10
                                        }).add();

                                label.align(Highcharts.extend(label
                                        .getBBox(), {
                                    align : 'left',
                                    x : 0, // offset
                                    verticalAlign : 'bottom',
                                    y : (60)
                                // offset
                                }), null, 'spacingBox');

                                var roundingNote = this.renderer.text('The sum of percentages may not be equal to 100% due to rounding off.', 10, (this.chartHeight-5))
                                .css({
                                    color: '#808080',
                                    fontSize: '12px'
                                }).add();
                            }
                        },
                        spacingBottom: 80,
                        spacingRight: 50
                    },
                    title : {
                        text : titleLbl
                    },
                    subtitle : {
                        text : subTtlLbl
                    },
                    xAxis : {
                        categories : keys,
                        labels : {
                            align : 'right',
                            style : {
                                textOverflow : 'none',
                                fontSize : '13px'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis : {
                        title : {
                            text : null
                        },
                        min : 0,
                        gridLineWidth : 0,
                        reversedStacks : false,
                        allowDecimals : false,
                        tickInterval : 10
                    },
                    legend : {
                        enabled : false,
                    },
                    tooltip : {
                        headerFormat : '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                        pointFormat : '{series.name}: {point.y}'
                    },
                    plotOptions : {
                        bar : {
                            dataLabels : {
                                crop : false,
                                overflow : 'none',
                                enabled : true,
                                color : 'black',
                                style : {

                                    fontSize : '12px'
                                },
                                formatter : function() {
                                    var index = productTypeList
                                            .indexOf(this.x);
                                    var yesNum = yesList[index];
                                    var noNum = noList[index];
                                    var percentage = (yesNum / (yesNum + noNum)) * 100;
                                    return this.y
                                            + ' ('
                                            + Highcharts.numberFormat(
                                                    percentage, 0) + '%)';
                                    // return this.y;
                                },
                                style : {
                                    fontWeight : null
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series : {
                            pointWidth : 18,
                            grouping : false,
                            groupPadding : 2,

                        }
                    },
                    series : [ {
                        colorByPoint : true,
                        name : 'Yes',
                        data : yesList
                    } ],
                    exporting : {
                        enabled : false,
                        filename : filename,
                        sourceWidth : 1000,
                        sourceHeight : 600
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour - adjust the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mavkcgug/ to show the issue and give the details about browser/os you use.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 14.04 with Apache Tomcat 8 as my development machine and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS as deployment server with Apache Tomcat 7 and Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) and Mozilla Firefox 44.0.2 to view the site. I am able to reproduce the bugs in my browsers when I download the PDF using the jsFiddle you have created. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on Ubuntu. It seems like a bug appeared on a specific os. I could workaround this issue by using offline exporting module - https://jsfiddle.net/mavkcgug/1/